# What to do with damaged batteries?

Tags: repair, equipment-damage, battery

I have a damaged LP-E6 battery, looks to be just a cracked plastic shell but retiring it just to be safe.

Looking for what to do with it now. Take it somewhere to be recycled? Does Canon or B&H/Adorama have a recycle plan I can get credit for it? Repair it (probably not worth it in this case)?

[image]

Comment: I doubt that anybody cares to collect them, as they come for two to three dollar a piece - there is no buffer for a ny such program. (Yes, Canon sells them for 30 $, but the original manufacturer sells them in parallel for '4 for 9.99', so that's what they are worth)

Comment: Canon sells them for $65.

Comment: That's not even a crack in the case, it's the top half of the shell separating from the bottom half where there probably wasn't enough glue used when the two pieces were joined as the battery was made. Assuming there's no swelling/leakage of the cells inside, I've taped them back together and kept using them.

Comment: @MichaelC There does seem to be a little swelling or at least what's looks like to be swelling. Originally I was just gonna do that too but since these batteries are used to be outside in the Florida humidity for a few days at a time I'd say better safe than sorry.

Comment: @SethKurkowski If there's any indication of swelling it's time to dispose of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your local authority will have recycle locations; even supermarkets have battery bins in the doorway. You're not going to get any money for it, it's scrap, but it should not go in landfill.

Comment: Supermarkets where you are at may have battery bins in the doorway. I've never seen one at any supermarket in the U.S. Where I live we have to wait until "hazardous materials day" about one Saturday a month and take them to our local trash transfer facility.

Comment: I found a locator system for the US -https://www.energizer.com/responsibility/battery-recycling/where-to-recycle-batteries In the EU battery recycling is compulsory [though no-one can really enforce that practically]. Apparently no-one can make it profitable, so it has to be government supported. In the UK, the regular garbage/trash/rubbish collectors don't take them, but local council recycling centres do, and almost all supermarkets, toy stores, anywhere that sells batteries also collects them for recycle,

Comment: Many big-box home improvement stores in the US have battery recycling drop boxes along side the CFL drop boxes. [The middle of this bin](https://images.app.goo.gl/n4fyE7XiFPAGCCJb8), for example.

Comment: Yes, i saw on the link provided by @Tetsujin that Home Depot and Lowes take them. That's good to know. It beats trying to remember to get up on the right Saturday morning to take them to the City collection site.